# Windows 7 only boots to Windows boot manager with Continue Recovery not going anywhere

Tags: bootcamp, startup, windows

Windows 7 Boot Camp doesn't boot on MacBook Air 2011. The only option I get in Windows boot manager is "Continue Recovery",

If I press "Continue Recovery", I get a black screen with flashing cursor. macOS boots as normal. I wanted to boot Windows in Safe Mode to try repairing it there. However, there is no reaction on either F8 or fn+F8: whatever I press I'm being brought back to Windows Boot Manager.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. The F8 key takes you to the boot manager. But you say there is no reaction when pressing the F8 key. If you can not reach the boot manager, then how are you selecting the boot manager options?

Comment: @DavidAnderson When Windows starts it automatically takes me to the boot manager, however, the only option I get is "Continue recovery".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A normal Boot Camp assisted install of Windows 7 on your model Mac places the System Reserved and Windows Recovery Environment (WRE) files on the same partition as Windows 7. So, if your Windows 7 partition has been compromised, then  you may not be able to correctly access the boot manager or the recovery files. Basically, Boot Camp places all your eggs in one basket.

The correct procedure would be to boot from the original installation media and select "Repair your computer", when the image below appears.

[image: v1]